# difference between strncpy and strxfrm

Tags: c

I can't seem to get my head around this, what is the basic difference between these two functions:

```
char *strncpy(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t  count);
```

and

```
size_t strxfrm(char *str1, const char *str2, size_t  count);
```

To me it seems they both copy `count` characters from `str2` to `str1`. What I really want to know is, when should I use either of them?

Comment: [strxfrm.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strxfrm.html) defines the difference in DESCRIPTION itself.

Comment: much obliged, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the **return value**:

The **strcpy()** and **strncpy()** functions return a **pointer** to the destination string.

Upon successful completion, **strxfrm()** shall return the **length** of the transformed string (not including the terminating null byte). If the value returned is n or more, the contents of the array pointed to by s1 are unspecified.

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted. It's simply not true. While the return values are not the same, the functions do not do the same thing either. strcpy copies the contents of s2 into s1, while strxfrm transforms the characters in s2 into something which will make strcmp return the same results as strcoll for two strings that have been transformed. strxfrm then places the resulting characters in s1. This MAY be the same content, but it's equally likely that it will be something not even printable.

Comment: As far as I tested with different inputs, the integer, which the function returns, is the length of "argument 2" (source string), not counting "argument 2"'s null terminator.

According to the description - returns the value of the transformed string (which I understand as "destination" or "argument 1"). Obviosly not true.

And second thing which is more confusing for me - why is this function considered to belongs to the "comparison" functions in "string.h", and not to the "copying" functions, like "strcpy" or "strncpy". Why?